# Не могу вызвать DialogFragment из canvas

Tags: android, canvas

Добрый день.
Не могу вызвать `DialogFragment` из `canvas`.
Рисую на canvas 4 точки, потом их нахожу, но как при их нажатие вызвать `DialogFragment` что бы к примеру подписать эту точку!? Как то не получается, нужна помощь.... 
Код:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    canvas.drawPath(mpath, mpaint);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x=event.getX();
    float y=event.getY();
    switch (event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

        if (i<4) {
            path.addCircle(x, y, 30, Path.Direction.CW);
            point = new Point(x, y);
            obgect.add(point);
            poin=false;
        } else {
            for (Point o:obgect) {
                if (x >= o.x - 30 && x <= o.x + 30 && y >= o.y - 30 && y <= o.y + 30) {
                    mpath.addCircle(o.x, o.y, 30, Path.Direction.CW);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    i++;
    invalidate();
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: форматируйте в следующий раз код сами

Comment: Не вижу, чтобы у вас не получалось вызвать `DialogFragment`. Вижу, что вы его нигде не пытались вызвать. Объясните, где он вам нужен, и для чего.

Comment: пробовал так: if (x >= o.x - 30 && x <= o.x + 30 && y >= o.y - 30 && y <= o.y + 30) {
                        mpath.addCircle(o.x, o.y, 30, Path.Direction.CW);
                        DialogFragment fragment = new DialogFragment();
                       fragment.show(getFragentManager(),"DailogFragment");
                    }

Comment: нужно для того что бы подписать точку или задать определенные параметры.

Comment: Ну, и в чем проблема? Что не получается? Это не очевидно

Comment: я так понимаю таким способом с canvas не вызвать Dialog, нужно каким то образом на точки повесить слушатель а после этого только вызывать, а как это сделать не пойму